# Counting compares for algorithm analysis

Tags: algorithm

Let's say I'm analyzing an algorithm and I want to count compares.

Assuming a structure like this:

```
if (a == b){
  ...
}
else if (a == c) {
  ...
}
else if (a == d) {
  ...
}
else {
  ...
}
```

What's the best way to count the compares?

I'm thinking this is the way to go:

```
int compare = 0

compares++; //will always do the first compare
if (a == b){
  ...
}
else if (a == c) {
  compares++; //add another because we got here
  ...
}
else if (a == d) {
  compares += 2; //add 2 because of this one and the previous else if
  ...
}
else {
  compares += 3; //etc
  ...
}
```

Is this correct?

Comment: Looks good, if overdone: don't increment `compares` before the chain-of-`if`s _if_ you are going to increase it in every branch, anyways. The object-oriented alternative would have an instance of a Comparator class do the bookkeeping. Keep the counts in a safe place, and try to convert to tree-of-`if`s (decision tree). Play with order of comparisons.

Comment: (To pick a nit: the number of comparisons in the `else`-statement in a chain-of-`if`s is the same as in its `then`-statement, not one higher.)

Comment: @greybeard: Wow!  That's not a nit that's a huge error!  The increment in the `else` should be `+= 2` not 3 because there is no additional compare happening to get in there.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's correct, but you can write it more succintly and more robustly (assuming this is C/C++/JS) using the c[omma operator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma_operator):

```
if (compares++, a == b){
  ...
}
else if (compares++, a == c) {
  ...
}
else if (compares++, a == d) {
  ...
}
else {
  ...
}
```

Also, if you're using C++ (or any language that has operator overloading), you can use custom objects and override the comparison operator and count it there. That way you only have to alter the type of the variables and not the rest of the code.

Comment: I wish it was C++ but it's Java.  I wrote the question this way for the sake of readability.  In the project I'm using a custom object for the analysis and was just thinking earlier how I'd love to be able to overload the "++" operator!

Comment: you *can* override `.equals`!

Comment: Although I do not like the idea of overloading == (since it will do "not obvious" things), I must say that the comma operator was a cool idea. I have never seen it that way.

Comment: Thinking deeper about overloading `==`, how would you modify `compares` value in case it is not a global variable/class attribute?

Comment: yes, you can use a global variable, or a static class variable. you can also modify through a reference/pointer, so it can be pretty much anywhere (as long as it is kept alive)

Answer (score 0):

If you are analyzing the algorithms in general you should use Big O and assume the worst case scenario. You are trying to see if one of the values in a collection is equal to another. In the worst case you will have to do **n-1-1 comparisons** so the algorithm grows linearly where n is the number of values in the collection. So you can classify the algorithm as **O(n)**.

If you want to compare quantitatively make sure to compare the values in the same order in each algorithm since that will change the results. Then what if `a` is equal to multiple values?